# Control neovim via pynvim from jupyter notebook

Tags: neovim

I've got a jupyter notebook, from which I want to control an instance of neovim. Following the instructions in [the pynvim repo](https://github.com/neovim/pynvim#usage-from-the-python-repl), I can setup neovim to listen like so:

```sh
NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS=/tmp/nvim nvim
```

and then I can control that instance of neovim from a regular (non-notebook) python session like so:

```py
from pynvim import attach
nvim = attach('socket', path='/tmp/nvim')
nvim.command('vsplit')
```

The above all works fine from a regular python session (`python3` or `ipython`) but it doesn't work from a jupyter notebook. Trying to run the following cell:

```py
from pynvim import attach
nvim = attach('socket', path='/tmp/nvim')
```

Results in the following error:

```
 RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [9], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 # %pip install pynvim
      2 from pynvim import attach
----> 3 nvim = attach('socket', path='/tmp/nvim')

File ~/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/pynvim/__init__.py:111, in attach(session_type, address, port, path, argv, decode)
     80 def attach(session_type, address=None, port=None,
     81            path=None, argv=None, decode=None):
     82     """Provide a nicer interface to create python api sessions.
     83 
     84     Previous machinery to create python api sessions is still there. This only
   (...)
    108 
    109     """
    110     session = (tcp_session(address, port) if session_type == 'tcp' else
--> 111                socket_session(path) if session_type == 'socket' else
    112                stdio_session() if session_type == 'stdio' else
    113                child_session(argv) if session_type == 'child' else
    114                None)
    116     if not session:
    117         raise Exception('Unknown session type "%s"' % session_type)

File ~/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/pynvim/msgpack_rpc/__init__.py:35, in socket_session(path)
     33 def socket_session(path):
     34     """Create a msgpack-rpc session from a unix domain socket."""
---> 35     return session('socket', path)

File ~/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/pynvim/msgpack_rpc/__init__.py:19, in session(transport_type, *args, **kwargs)
     18 def session(transport_type='stdio', *args, **kwargs):
---> 19     loop = EventLoop(transport_type, *args, **kwargs)
     20     msgpack_stream = MsgpackStream(loop)
     21     async_session = AsyncSession(msgpack_stream)

File ~/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/pynvim/msgpack_rpc/event_loop/base.py:93, in BaseEventLoop.__init__(self, transport_type, *args)
     91 except Exception as e:
     92     self.close()
---> 93     raise e
     94 self._start_reading()

File ~/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/pynvim/msgpack_rpc/event_loop/base.py:90, in BaseEventLoop.__init__(self, transport_type, *args)
     88 self._init()
     89 try:
---> 90     getattr(self, '_connect_{}'.format(transport_type))(*args)
     91 except Exception as e:
     92     self.close()

File ~/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/pynvim/msgpack_rpc/event_loop/asyncio.py:96, in AsyncioEventLoop._connect_socket(self, path)
     94 else:
     95     coroutine = self._loop.create_unix_connection(self._fact, path)
---> 96 self._loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py:622, in BaseEventLoop.run_until_complete(self, future)
    611 """Run until the Future is done.
    612 
    613 If the argument is a coroutine, it is wrapped in a Task.
   (...)
    619 Return the Future's result, or raise its exception.
    620 """
    621 self._check_closed()
--> 622 self._check_running()
    624 new_task = not futures.isfuture(future)
    625 future = tasks.ensure_future(future, loop=self)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py:584, in BaseEventLoop._check_running(self)
    582     raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
    583 if events._get_running_loop() is not None:
--> 584     raise RuntimeError(
    585         'Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running')

RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running
```

Which looks like both jupyter and pynvim are trying to run async loops at the same time. I'm not sure how to get around the issue though.

How can I control neovim from a python jupyter notebook?